# A verb to describe all possible precaution measures one takes in order to provide safety for some of his very valued things

Tags: word-choice

What's the best verb in English to describe all possible precaution measures one takes in order to provide safety for some of his very valued things?

For example, he _____________ this gemstone all his life.

Guarded, secured, cherished, protected or simply kept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use "keep secure":

> He **kept** his father's antique watch **secure** his entire life, until he passed it on to his own son.

Unless you mean in some specific situation where he *protected* the item:

> He intended **to guard** his father's antique watch **with his life**.

The idiom "with one's life" means to be willing to risk dying in order to achieve some goal, and so implies *extreme* protection.